# Error render "before all" hook FAILED - React + Karma

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, karma-runner, chai

I am using Karma to run my test cases in React application but getting error in following file, `before` statement is not getting executed as expected The error description is also mentioned below:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import Heading from 'lib/component/common/Heading/Heading';
import renderAndReturnOutput from '../../../testutils/renderAndReturnOutput.js';
import {findType} from '../../../testutils/shallowHelpers.js';
import { assert } from 'chai';
describe('component/common/Heading', () => {
    describe('render', () => {
        let output,
            props;
        before(() => { 
            props = {};
            output = renderAndReturnOutput(Heading, props).output;
        });
        it('should load Heading view', () => {  
            assert.ok(findType(output, 'div'));
        });     
    });  
});
/* eslint-enable no-undef */
```

Error description:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) component/common/Button render "before all" hook FAILED
        null is not an object (evaluating 'getReactDOM().__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')
        getReactTestUtils@C:/Vishal/UI/poc1/risk-oda/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js:476:25
        get@C:/Vishal/UI/poc1/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js:3197:58
        default@C:/Vishal/UI/poc1/testlib/unit/testutils/renderAndReturnOutput.js:4:57
        C:/Vishal/UI/poc1/testlib/unit/component/common/Button/Button-test.js:16:62
```

Snippet of my `package.json` to highlight the NPM Versions used are mentioned below:

```
"karma": "^0.13.3",
"react": "^15.1.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.1.0",
"react-redux": "~4.4.5",
"react-shallow-renderer-helpers": "^2.0.2",
"redux": "~3.5.2"
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: According to the stack trace the prob lies with *renderAndReturnOutput*. It might be that Heading or props parameters are null or do not contain the correct infomation. I would have commented this but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: tried, did not work!